# Reading Checkbox values in MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have looked at various ways of reading CheckBook values in my Index.cshtml file but so far none seem to work for me.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - Logger Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { action = "Employees" }))
{
    <header>
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                @Html.CheckBox("item1", true))
                <label for="coding">Coding</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.CheckBox("item1", false)
                <label for="music">Music</label>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logger", "Employees", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" }),</li>
                </ul>
```

.........

My Model is

```
  public class Employees
  {
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public bool item1 { get; set; }
    public bool item2 { get; set; }
    public class LogBookContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Post in the Controller is

```
 public IActionResult Employees()
    {

        string query = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,Lastname,Address,City,Region,PostalCode FROM Employees";
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, "Data Source=Owner-PC;Initial Catalog=NORTHWND;Integrated Security=True");
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(data);
        return View(data);
    }
```

What I am attempting is to return various checkBox values to use to create the query string instead of a fixed query string.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Normally you would want your Controller Action to accept a parameter of the Model, so that the ModelBinder deals with the inputs and "packages" them up for you. In that case your method would look be 

public IActionResult Employees(Employees model)

and then you could read model.item1 and model.item2 and use them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I added to the top of my View

```
 @model LogBook.Models.Employees
```

Also changed the @CheckBox to 
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.item1, new { @class = "Employees" })

at the top and in the Controller

```
 public IActionResult Employees2(Employees model)
```

As you can see I have item1 set to a true and item2 set default to false. When i run the program in debug mode, I have it stop at

```
 public IActionResult Employees2(Employees model)
    {
        bool item1 = model.item1;
        bool item2 = model.item2;
```

Both Model.item1 and Model.item2 are still false.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. If your using @ActionLink to get back to your controller, it will not return the values of things like CheckBox, RadioBox, and etc tied to my model. What I had to do was use the Input Submit and a {HttpPost] Index routine. Then I could see the Checkboxs change in my model. Then do a RedirectView to my Controller routine that handled things and sent the result out to a view. So why would using a @ActionLink button not return model items tied to a Checkbox?